# php & mysql: Proper handling of all types of queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I would like to make one universal function for database queries.
The function I have below works perfectly for SELECT queries.
However I would like to have it working properly for INSERT, UPDATE,
DROP and other queries not returning anything. Can someone tell me
why using mysqli_fetch_all for such queries prints warning? How
to properly handle it? How to obtain status of such queries?

```
function cms_query($sql_query)
{
    // Object returned by mysqli_connect
    global $cms_db;

    // Perform query
    $result = mysqli_query($cms_db, $sql_query);
    if(!$result) {
        print("ERROR\nFAILED_TO_QUERY\n");
        return;
    }

    // Obtain results
    $rows = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
    if(!$rows) {
        print("OK\n0\n0\n");
        return;
    }

    // Print result array keys
    $keys = array_keys($rows[0]);
    print("OK\n" . count($keys) . "\n");
    foreach($keys as $key)
        print($key . "\n");

    // Print result rows
    print(count($rows) . "\n");
    foreach($rows as $row)
        foreach($row as $value)
            print($value . "\n");
}
```

Comment: What's the warning?

Comment: is the MySQL Native Driver installed on the system? (this for `mysqli_fetch_all()`) You should check for the real errors here, rather than what you're using now with `mysqli_error($cms_db)` and php's error reporting.

Comment: so there; your query failed and I told you what to use; so use it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a good idea *per se* to have such a function, but there is one thing that your function desperately lacking - the support for **prepared statements**.

So, to make your function work in its current form, it's not a big deal:

```
function cms_query($sql_query)
{
    // Object returned by mysqli_connect
    global $cms_db;

    // Perform query
    $result = mysqli_query($cms_db, $sql_query);
    if(!$result) {
        trigger_error(mysqli_error($cms_db));
    }

    // if it was a DML query
    if (if $result === true)
    {
        return;
    }

    // Obtain results
    return mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
```

but you have to understand that such a function should support prepared statements. And for sake of such a support it's better to use PDO. I wrote such a function, or rather, a [PDO wrapper](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) which I strongly recommend for you to consider. Note the Examples part of the article - as you can see, this function can run any kind of query.

Comment: Great idea! That is what I was actually looking for :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

> ### `mysqli_query`
>
> Returns `FALSE` on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries `mysqli_query()` will return a `mysqli_result` object. For other successful queries `mysqli_query()` will return TRUE.

So, when you do a data modification query (INSERT for example), you get boolean value. When you try to pass it as argument for [`mysqli_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) you get an error, because this function expects an instance of [`mysqli_result`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) class.